# Ubuntu Nvidia GTX 960M

Tags: nvidia

I promise that I've tried to find the answer for days and days.
I've come accross of dozens and dozens of indications, explanations, opinions and so on.
And... nothing.
I am tired of rebooting my notebook.

MSI PE60 6QE  Nvidia GTX 960M
Fresh installation

Well-known error while trying to install

Try to set nomodeset but There Is No nomodeset in my Ubuntu DVD.

Help will be sincerely appreciated.

I've forgot to say that I am absolutely new to Linux. New. Never tried it.
I am tired of Windows but if installing Ubuntu is so complicated I think I will offer my notebook and forget just about everything. Back to the pencil and the paper.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for being frustrated.
Boot from Ubuntu installation media.

Highlight Try Ubuntu without installing and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu Live desktop.

Click on Install Ubuntu and start the system installation.
When finished, reboot into the installed Ubuntu system.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

First of all install the NVIDIA drivers and reboot the system.
Now you don't have to add `nouveau.modeset=0` anymore ...

Comment: Thnks for your answer but it hasn't work maybe because I am not writting the command where I should.

Comment: Thnks for your answer but it hasn't work maybe because I am not writting the command where I should. I've placed it at the end of the Linux line: ...quiet splash -- nouveau.modeset=0, didn't work; then at the end of the Linux line: ...quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 --, didn't work; and finally between Linux and the third and last line, didn't work. Still the same error.

Comment: @user513831 : You have to write it without "--" ! Please try again and in case it still does not work, use the parameter nomodeset instead of  nouveau.modeset=0 - and important : put a space before the parameter.

Comment: I haven't used any quotes. My doubt was about where in the line should I place the parameter assuming that the Linux line finishes like this: ...quiet splash --

Comment: As I told you in my first comment I've already tried all those three combinations. I've just tried with nomodeset and as I say in my first post,doesn't work neither. Thank you very much for time anyway.

Comment: @user513831 : Maybe you have to disable the NVIDIA graphics card in BIOS and re-enable it afterwards - otherwise I am running out of ideas ... the instructions I gave you have worked fine in nearly every case. :)

Comment: Unfortunately no option to disable or enable graphic card in BIOS.

Comment: @user513831 : Some last ideas : What about the installation media ? Did you download the recommended 64 bit Ubuntu edition - is the installation media configured properly -did you disable Secure Boot in BIOS ?

Comment: Yes 64 bit edition downloaded from Ubuntu org; Secure Boot, Fast Boot disabled. Just for the record for future readers the error message says: [0,176607] ACPI : EC : Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected.     I've found that this error is related to GTX 960M graphic card. Anyway, big thanks cl-netbox for your time and patience.

Comment: @user513831 : You're welcome ! This might be a hint for a hardware failure, maybe a BIOS flash can fix it ... you should contact the hardware vendor. :)

Comment: I've also reflashed my BIOS. This is why I started saying that I tried all I could try (for the moment) :)